# What is the declesion of `В лесу` in this phrase: "В лесу Волк встретил Красную Шапочку"? why?

Tags: грамматика

It may be locative or dative, i am not used to locative declensions but if it is dative, why should be it?

This question is claimed to be duplicate, but i truly can not see the similarity between this question and the one appointed in the duplication claim. Because i am searching the grammatical aspect of this declension, i gave an example, but i do not want an example, i want to understand why this declension was used, where more it is used, and how it may be used in another cases. thank you.

Comment: It is locative.

Comment: locative it is.

Comment: I searched "declension в лесу" at this site, and found 5 such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is locative indeed.

It's a homograph of dative, however it differs in stress: locative is *лесу́* (*я гуляю в лесу́*), dative is *ле́су* (*я вышел к ле́су*).

Locative forms exist for a quite large, if limited, number of II and III declension nouns (those ending in a consonant or *-ь* in nominative), mostly having monosyllabic roots. Usually they designate something things can "be in": enclosures (*лес, берег, тень*); containers (*шкаф, короб, гроб*); substances and materials (*мёд, пух, спирт*); states (*бой, бред, тишь*); some proper nouns (*Крым*, *Клин*, *Дон*) etc.

Whether or not any given noun has a locative is something you have to learn by heart, and some nouns can confuse even native Russian speakers: *пляж, мел, отпуск* all technically have locative, however, using the locative form of these nouns sounds quite peculiar to a modern Russian speaker's ear.

Some homonyms have a locative in one meaning and don't have it in another: *мир* meaning "world" or "peace" does not have a locative; the same word meaning "society" or "laity" does have it.

It is used with the prepositions *в* and *на*, and, as the name suggests, mostly it means that something is "in" or "on" the object: *гулять в лесу́; быть в раю́*. It can also have some secondary meanings: "to be covered or treated with" (*рыльце в пуху́; курица в меду́; настойка на спирту́*, etc., similar to English "chicken in honey sauce"), "to play on" (*играть на басу́*), "to swear on" (*клясться на крови́*) and others.

In yet other meanings the prepositional is used with the same prepositions: *видеть в мёде источник богатства* ("to see honey as a source of wealth"), *делать деньги на мехе* ("to make money out of furs") etc. In both cases above, *в* and *на* do not mean "in" or "on" in their usual sense.